# How safe it is to assume whois ip network /24 belogns to same hosting company?

Tags: networking, ip

I found this, but I don't think it answears my question: [Is it safe to assume that two hosts on the same /24 network belong to the same AS-number?](https://serverfault.com/questions/93871/is-it-safe-to-assume-that-two-hosts-on-the-same-24-network-belong-to-the-same-a)

I have online shop, on which somone is spamming massievely shopping carts. That IP belongs to a company which I found by using who.is https://who.is/whois-ip/ip-address/38.99.82.254

It states that their IP network is: `network:IP-Network:38.99.82.0/24`

Is it safe to assume that this network belongs to this company? So if I block by this IP mask I don't block some kind of legit ISP?

If no, then is there a way to determine what IP range should I block from this IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all belongs to FieldTech, Inc.
Searching for them I found [this](http://www.spambotsecurity.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=3014).

Comment: I more meant how safe from who.is is it to asuume that this network range belongs to them. I know it belongs to Fieldtech Inc since its in who.is. I want to know more about interpreting results of who.is

Comment: @Gacek To get more information than that, you'll need to speak with Fieldtech, the netblock owner.

Comment: So it's not part of who.is answear? So what is this `IP-Network` part? what does it say?

Comment: The whois results show that FieldTech owns the entire /24; if it was me I'd block the whole set -- if you assume that the WHOIS data is accurate (I do, mostly).

Comment: That's what I wanted to know! :)